# Remove an element from page flow similiar to a fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I was curious if there was a way to remove an element from the page flow similar to `position:fixed;`, such that the page won't scroll.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ErPcH/1/) - currently even though it goes beyond the screen it doesn't increase the size of the document, but if position is changed to absolute / relative it will.

I would like for the position to be absolute (although relative will work), yet not increase the document size.

I'm looking for ways to do this be it html/css work around, JavaScript, or jquery (even browser-specific solutions).

Comment: Are you expecting other content in the document that may be longer than the page height and you'd want the scroll bars? First thought it to just set the `body { overflow: hidden; }`. Other solution could be to set that element to `position:absolute` then wrap it in a div that is fixed and has it's height set to the page height with JS and give that `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what else you have on the page, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ErPcH/3/) might do the trick.

```
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


nav{
    width:98px;
    height:750px;
    background:blue;   
    position:absolute;
}
```

If you want other elements to overflow the body, use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ErPcH/4/) code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
</div>

body {
    height:100%;

}

.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav{
    width:98px;
    height:750px;
    background:blue;   
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: The second one is what I needed. Thanks for the help and posting 2 ways to do it.